# Xcode 8.3.1 can't login Apple id

Tags: xcode, apple-id

I use Xcode and login Apple id , but always get "apple id or password is incorrect" , I try go to apple dev web site and login the same apple id ,it's success , so I'm sure the apple id and pwd is correct . I don't know why can't login with Xcode.....

Comment: @lan Did u find any solutions?